# No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'X'

Tags: typescript, mapping

i Want to create my mongoose insert validation with typescript but i got an error

here my types for params:

```js
type OperationType = 'Insert' | 'Update' | 'Delete';

type Operator =  'Exists' | 'NotExists' | '>=' | '=<' | '>' | '<' |'true' | 'fasle'; 

type Properties<T> = Partial<T> | [Partial<T>];

type ValidateProp<T> = {fieldName:T  ,operator:Operator};

type Validation<V> = [ValidateProp<V>];
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeEiH.png)

```
const checkValidation = <T extends Document,K extends keyof T>(ValidateProps:Validation<K>,properties:Properties<T>,model:Model<T>) => {
```

if(ValidateProps.length){

```
if(typeof properties === 'object'){

   Object.keys(properties).forEach((prop) => {
    const validProp = ValidateProps.find(f => f.fieldName === prop);
    if(validProp){
      
      let entity: Partial<T> & Record<string, T[keyof T]> = {};
      
      entity[prop] =  properties[prop];
      

      switch (validProp.operator) {
        case 'Exists':
          model.find(entity)
          break;
      
        default:
          break;
      }
    }
  });

}
```

}

1. List item

}

in Object.key loop prop not consider as a key index in properties
**Error**

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Properties'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Properties'.ts(7053)

Comment: [Please consider replacing or supplementing images of text with the actual plain text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218).  Ideally you should provide plain-text code as a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) so that others can demonstrate the problem for themselves.

Comment: Hi Faizan, what error are you getting? Can you add your error message as text. I can't read it from the screenshot.

Comment: Hi Michael  i got that type of error (Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Properties<T>'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Properties<T>'.ts(7053)

Comment: U can zoom it  for proper result i was stack in over the weak kindly guid me where i did mistake

Comment: Hi Faizan, consider to edit your post to make it better readable. Posts in Stackoverflow should have a certain level of quality. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The object "prop" is an element from the array returned by Object.keys(), and therefore a string, so no need to cast it to any. That should solve the error that is showing in the screenshot.

Comment: without casting i got that type of error (Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Properties<T>'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Properties<T>'.ts(7053))